# Consolidate two ranges in date wise order in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am knew to google spreadsheet and trying to unite/consolidate two ranges in order, I am struggling hard with this & have written formula on spreadsheet but that is wrong.

Two Ranges are:

```
    Range-1 = D1:F12
D1:D12   E1:E12   F1:F12
Word      Date     Name

Range-2 = G1:I12

G1:G12   H1:H12   I1:I12
Word      Date     Name
```

Now I want to unite/consolidate Range-1 & Range 2 where words should appear in column A, Date should appear in column B & Name should appear in column C & criteria is that date of new range should be in ascending order.

You may please see below mentioned link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tiKUdREYudh1htLIfh9VSWO27N5zCXwJAVKr0gqaSXE/edit#gid=0

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=query({D1:F; G1:I}, "where Col1 <>'' ")
```

and see if that works.

If you need it ordered by date:

```
=query({D1:F; G1:I}, "where Col1 <>'' order by Col2")
```